# How can I get access to the Twitter Media Studio

Tags: twitter

I have seen we can do live streams and more through the Twitter Media Studio, but I don't have access for that. How can I gain access for that feature

Can I inform them through an email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter Media Studio is only available for limited audience. So I don't think you can request that feature to your account. But don't lose your moral ty reach them and gain that feature asap